# Cleaning JBoss AS 7.1 Standalone.xml

Tags: jboss7.x, eclipse-kepler

I couldn't find an answer to this in any other questions and I wanted to see if anyone knew. I'm using JBoss AS 7.1 on Kepler eclipse, and I was wondering if there is a way to change your standalone.xml while the server is running and have Jboss push the change. Would just cleaning the server do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit the raw XML files and see runtime changes. In fact there is a good chance any changes will be overwritten by the server.

The best way to make runtime changes is either via the web console or the CLI environment. I don't know if JBoss Tools has any kind of CLI type of client that can be used.